# xpath how to get the last value of first level of children in the case of the number of children is not always the same

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, parent-child

With the following code:

```
data = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="postInfo desktop"]/span[@class="nameBlock"]')
```

I got those html codes below:

```
<span class="nameBlock">
  <span class="name">Anonymous</span>
  <span class="posteruid id_RDS8pJvL">(ID:
    <span class="hand" title="Highlight posts by this ID" style="background-color: rgb(228, 51, 
    138); color: white;">RDS8pJvL</span>)</span>
  <span title="United States" class="flag flag-us"></span>
</span>
```

And

```
<span class="nameBlock">
  <span class="name">Pierre</span>
  <span class="postertrip">!AYZrMZsavE</span>
  <span class="posteruid id_y5EgihFc">(ID:
    <span class="hand" title="Highlight posts by this ID" 
    style="background-color: rgb(136, 179, 155); color: black;">y5EgihFc</span>)</span>
  <span title="Australia" class="flag flag-au"></span>
</span>
```

Now I need to get the "countries" => "United States" and "Australia".

With the whole dataset (more than 120k entries), I was doing:

```
for i in data:
 country = i.find_element(By.XPATH, './/span[contains(@class,"flag")]').get_attribute('title')
```

But after a while I got empty entries and I figured out than sometime the class of the country was completely changing from "flag something" to "bf something" or "cd something"

This is why I decided to go with the last children for each element:

```
for i in data:
 country = i.find_element(By.XPATH, './/span[3]').get_attribute('title')
```

But again, after a while I got error again because sometime there were some `<span class="postertrip">BLABLA</span>` popping, moving the "country" location to "span[4]".

So, I changed for the following one:

```
for i in data:
 country = i.find_element(By.XPATH, './/span[last()]').get_attribute('title')
```

But this last one always give me the second level child (*posteruid child*):

```
 <span class="hand" title="Highlight posts by this ID" 
        style="background-color: rgb(136, 179, 155); color: black;">y5EgihFc</span>)
```

**One thing that I'm certain: the country is ALWAYS the last child (*span*) of the first level of children.**

So I'm out of ideas this is why I'm asking you this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following `xpath` to always identify the last child of parent.

```
(//span[@class='nameBlock']//span[@title])[last()]
```

Code block.

```
for country in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "(//span[@class='nameBlock']//span[@title])[last()]"):
    print(country.get_attribute("title"))
```

Comment: Inspired by your answer I finally got it! Here's my final code: country = i.find_element(By.XPATH, '(.//span)[last()]').get_attribute('title')). The trick - as you pointed out - s to put the "last()" OUTSIDE, wrapping the "XPATH" in "()". Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For this particular case, you can get the titles without calculating the child nodes. Just keep the nameBlock as root and create the xpath to point to the child which class will have the title ( flag, in this case). Like this:

```
//span[@class='nameBlock']/span[contains(@class,'flag')]
```

[image]

Comment: You didn't read my whole question. This was my first solution but sometime there's no "flag" text/string in the class :)